# How can I add the value of a list item to a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to add the list item chosen to the textarea and if there's something written on the textarea the chosen list item will be added after it.

```js
$('#box li').click(function() {
  $('#id-of-your-textarea').append($(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="box">
  <li>Text1</li>
  <li>Text2</li>
  <li>Text3</li>
</ul>
<textarea id="id-of-your-textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: It's already working, you just need to add `textarea` to your HTML with an `id` and add that `id` to the `script`.

Comment: But if there's something written already on the textarea the li don't appear. I want it to be added to it.

Comment: I want to write and chose a li to add in the textarea.

Comment: Lists aren't intended for selection. You should use checkboxes, buttons, or a select element. This has accessibility problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I edited your snippet and honestly, jQuery is too much. If you are learning, I would strongly advise you to learn pure Javascript. It is literally the code that runs under hood of jQuery library.

Below is the snippet that runs like you want with only Javascript, no jQuery, no library, just pure JS.

```js
//Variables Needed for HTML Elements.

const textArea = document.getElementById('id-of-your-textarea'); 
const boxLi= document.getElementById('box').children;

for(let i = 0; i < boxLi.length; i++){ // Looping To All Children of Box.
  boxLi[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    textArea.value += boxLi[i].textContent + '\n' // Hey JS, do that when I click on that very Li element which is adding text Content of Li Element in the Text Area Value.
  })
}
```

```html
<ul id="box">
  <li>Text1</li>
  <li>Text2</li>
  <li>Text3</li>
</ul>
<textarea id="id-of-your-textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: And I would strongly suggest delegation instead of a for loop

Comment: `const textArea =  document.getElementById('id-of-your-textarea');
document.getElementById('box').addEventListener("click", e => textArea.value += e.target.textContent.trim());`

Answer (score 0):

A pure/vanilla javascript solution could be for example:

```js
function appendValue(event)
{
  const tgtTextArea = document.getElementById('textarea'); 
  let srcEl = event.target;
  if (srcEl.tagName == "LI")
  {
    tgtTextArea.value += srcEl.textContent + '\n';
  }
}

const options= document.getElementById('options');
options.addEventListener('click', appendValue);
```

```html
<ul id="options">
  <li>Text1</li>
  <li>Text2</li>
  <li>Text3</li>
</ul>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```